# Microsoft SQL Server - Recovery MASTER Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have backuped "master" database from 1 server and need to recovery it to another server. In "master" database or in another database - not matter. Just i need access data.

When i try restore it to "master" database - i have error "To restore the master database, the server must be running in single-user mode"

When i try restore to another new database, i have error:

> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 RESTORE DATABASE is terminating
> abnormally. Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Procedure columns, Line 2
> [Batch Start Line 0] SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based
> I/O error: torn page (expected signature: 0x55555555; actual
> signature: 0x15400c11). It occurred during a read of page (1:447) in
> database ID 8 at offset 0x0000000037e000 in file 'C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\kek4.mdf'.
> Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log
> may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that
> threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
> Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
> can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
> Books Online.

---

When i try to backup master DB and restore it to new DB on same server, not from 1 server to 2 server, all ok.

Whats wrong ? How can i do it ?

Comment: See [Restore the master Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-the-master-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If your need is to recover user data in master, I suggest you restore it to a ephemeral instance and extract needed data from there.

Comment: *"To restore the `master` database, the server must be running in single-user mode"* This means that to restore the `master` database, the server must be running in single-user mode. Have you tried putting it in single-user mode before restoring? Also why have you tagged both 2008 and 2012, are you trying to use different versions or build numbers to backup and restore?